# AngularJS , custom directive not working @ plnkr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have created a simple plnk @ plnkr.co. It doesn't work there.
However the same code works smooth in local.

plnk @ [plnkr.co link](http://embed.plnkr.co/qlXfFgF9jsh1eYbZtAiq/preview)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller='controller'>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div my-sample></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
// Code goes here
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app',[]).
controller('controller',function($scope)
{
  
}).directive('mySample',function($compile)
{
  return {
    link : function(scope,element,attrs,controller)
    {
      var markup = "<input type='text' ng-model='text' />{{text}}"
      angular.element(element).html($compile(markup)(scope));
    }
  }
});
```

The output in plnkr comes like :

Hello Plunker!

[[object HTMLInputElement], [object HTMLSpanElement]]

strange, however when i run the same in local html it renders just fine. Whats going on here ??

Also I am using angular js 1.2.6 its because thats what is being used in my work - production app ... so i am learning angular using 1.2.6 for now.

Comment: is there a need to use `$compile` service? Why not just to use `template` field? Here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/AAT7gIE1mhLsf0us6ojp?p=preview)

Comment: @IlyaIvanov , yes template does the job too. However I was going through  different ways of achieving the same result here. When it didn't work in plnkr, but worked in local it had me bit puzzled. I completely understand that for straightforward mark up needs I should use template. The pluralsight tutorial on angular js fundamentals by joe eames and cooper tells the same.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compile it a little differently.

```
element.html("<input type='text' ng-model='text' />{{text}}");
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MOVlG19nypGnctvMsryK?p=preview)

Just a quick word: I'm assuming what you did here is simplified and in your real case there is a need to compile your template, because at the moment there isn't.

Comment: OP is saying the same code is working in local then what is the scenario for that ?

Comment: @squiroid Not sure how it's working there, the plunker doesn't work as well and the compiling doesn't seem right. (html insertion after compile)

Comment: Strange! it works, ok I know it shouldn't be strange, but whats different when its being done with plnkr ? @OmriAharon , yes ofcourse, I am just trying out different ways of achieving the same. I should just use template for simple markup needs, and link for more complex ... and yet to go through the complete tut ... However this behaviour at plnkr has me confounded.